# UIFont in monotouch iOS 7.0.2

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios7, xamarin, uifont

I just update my montouch to xamarin.iOS 7.0.2. before that I have this code in my project:

```
nameTextView .Font = new UIFont ().WithSize (10);
```

but it is not working now.

I face with this error:

```
Error CS0619: `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIFont.UIFont()' is obsolete: `This constructor does not return a valid, default, instance'
```

Now, how should I use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nameTextView.Font = UIFont.FromName(UIFont.PreferredBody.Name, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

**http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial**

This tutorial link for customized Text kit property.Check this may be it help full.

**self.textView.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
self.textView.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];**

In iOS 7 into syntax are changed.It's something like that HTML property.